# PHP: put a variable inside a variable, or edit the variable

Tags: php, variables

I'm pretty new to PHP, got a question, I can't figure out after few research.

Here is my sample code

```php
<?php 
    $sample = '<div class="sample"><ul><li>123</li><li></li></ul></div>';
    $newsample = '<span class="newsample">11</span>';
    /* Some code here to put the $newsample variable inside $sample */
?>
```

My expected output is like below:

```html
<div class="sample">
    <li>123</li>
    <li><span class="newsample">11</span></li>
</div>
```

Is there anyway we can do that?

Comment: You need to define `$newsample` first, then, use [concatenation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) to build the final string (ex: https://3v4l.org/BDcNj)

Comment: Hi Syscall, thanks for the solution there!  Although I was thinking how I can add $newsample inside $sample without knowing how $sample(html structure) looks like. But this works anyway, when I print out $sample, and define new variable and combining these two.